# JavaScript WebApi references: where to store them?

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Im new to javascript and want to start writing code as clean(correct) as possible. I use C# WebApi as backend and simple pure HTML + JavaScript project for frontend. 
Up until now I stored configuration for my frontend in javascript files like this:

```
var serviceUri = 'http://localhost:666/api/service';
```

And just use them somewhere.

In real applications this should be outside any javascript files, at least in my opinion. Similar to how I do it with .NET stand-alone applications or WCF services. How I should store this kind of configuration for frontend application? What is best practises?

Comment: Can you dynamically render (on the server) the URI string into the Javascript you're serving, or does "simple pure HTML + JavaScript" mean that those are static files being served?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify the server location of the web api in javascript. If you just use `var serviceUri = '/api/service';` it will take the current server location of your page.

And if you are using static files the problem that you have to change the service location both in the js and the web api will remain and cannot be get rid of without you implementing your own compile tools (which will be a pain in the ass to find the correct routing and so on).

In the enterprise solutions I've worked on we just deal with it. You could create a js file to have all the api endpoints in one place but this could easly get ugly when there are to many.

Comment: So, basically it is common to see some config.js file which contains configuration for API? My WebApi is in ideal case can reside on different servers (for example production server and test server)

Comment: @eocron06 we do not save our web api endpoints in one js file but per context in which we are using it. For us this is in the angluar-js services and directives. And if there are changes in routing then the person doing the changes has to be aware of the references (they are easy to find with a quick regex search). But for a smaller project I would recommend saving them in one file.